# Why I cannot see an function that is part of an imported module's imported module in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, scope, import-module

Let me explain with a simple example:

```
# TestModule.psm1 content 
# which is D:\Projects\(...)\MyProject\\bin\Debug\Modules directory :
function TestMe
{
 Write-Output "TestMe is called!"
}


# SetUpTools.psm1 content 
# which is D:\Projects\(...)\MyProject\\bin\Debug directory :
function Import-AllModulesInside ([string]$path = $(throw "You must specify a path where to import the contents"))
{

    if ( $(Test-Path $path)-eq $false){
        throw "The path to use for importing modules is not valid: $path"}


        # Import all modules in the specified path
        dir ($path | where {!$_.PsIsContainer} )| %{
        $moduleName = $($path + "\" + $_.name)

        import-module "$moduleName"
        Write-Output "importing $moduleName"

        }
}


#MainScript.ps1 content which is D:\Projects\(...)\MyProject\\bin\Debug directory :

# Config values are loaded in the begining
# (......)

# Import SetUpTools.psm1:

 Import-Module SetUpTools.psm1 


# Gets the modules directory's full path which I have loaded before..
$modulesPath = $(Get-ScriptDirectory) + $appSettings["ModulesFullPath"]


Write-Output ($modulesPath) # which writes : D:\Projects\(...)\MyProject\\bin\Debug\Modules

Import-AllModulesInside $modulesPath #Calls the method in SetUpTools.psm1

# I expect TestModule function to be available now:

TestMe  # But PowerShell does not recognize this function as I have not imported it in the main script.
```

But when I remove the Import-AllModulesInside function to the main script, then TestMe is callable.

I want function Import-AllModulesInside to be part of my SetUp tools.

**Question:**
How can I make the imported-modules that were imported by an imported module assessable to the main script?

Comment: The reason for this is that you typically import a module to do something you care about, but you don't want its internal implementation (such as what other modules it makes use of) all over your powershell session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import-module -scope global should do the trick :)

for PS V2 il would be import-module -global  ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd819454.aspx )